# Symfony4 Forms - EntityType with two choice_label

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms, symfony4

I'm pretty new to symfony and symfony forms.

I have a form with an EntityType, that looks like this:

```
->add('customer', EntityType::class, [
    'label' => 'Kunde: ',
    'class' => Customer::class,
    'choice_label' => 'Name',
    'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
        return $er->createQueryBuilder('c')
            ->select('CONCAT(c.firstname, " ", c.surname) AS Name');
    }
])
```

But I now get an Error/Warning:

`Warning: spl_object_hash() expects parameter 1 to be object, string given`

[image]

**Customer Entity:**

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\CustomerRepository")
 */
class Customer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
     private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="firstname", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    private $firstname;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="surname", type="string", length=50, nullable=false)
     */
    private $surname;

    ...
```

Thank you very much for your time and help.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You could also simply use a callback for the [`choice_label`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html#choice-label)

E.g.:

```
->add('customer', EntityType::class, [
    'label' => 'Kunde: ',
    'class' => Customer::class,
    'choice_label' => function (Customer $customer) {
        return $customer->getFirstname() . ' ' . $customer->getSurname();

        // or better, move this logic to Customer, and return:
        // return $customer->getFullname();
    },
])
```

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this works with Symfony 4 but it does work with symfony 5. This is more of an extension of Yoshis' answer than a new answer.

If you create a `getFullname()` function as suggested by Yoshi you can do the following.

Customer.php:

```
public function getFullname(): ?string {
    return $this->firstname . ' ' . $this->surname;
}
```

Then in your form:

```
->add('customer', EntityType::class, [
    'label' => 'Kunde: ',
    'class' => Customer::class,
    'choice_label' => 'fullname'
])
```

Adding the fullname function to the customer also allows you to use fullname within your twig files.

eg.

```
{{ customer.fullname }}
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you created a `__toString()` method in your customer entity.

```
/**
 * toString
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function __toString() {
    return $this->getFirstname().' '.$this->getSurname();
}
```

Then, something like this should be enough :

```
->add('customer')
```

If customer is related to your entityType, this should be enough

Comment: You meant `CONCAT` right? Now I got this error: `Error: Expected StateFieldPathExpression | string | InputParameter | FunctionsReturningStrings | AggregateExpression, got '"'`

Comment: yeah, I meant `CONCAT` sorry... As for your current eror, we would need more details, I think you should edit and update your current question.

Comment: I updated my question. What details do you need, the Entity, Controller, Stack Trace?

Comment: @Dario can you also add your user entity?! (just the parameters, no need of the getters/setters)

Comment: I edited my question and added the `customer` entity.

Comment: @Dario Edited my answer... This one is more simple if there is a relation between the two entities